# Advance NSOperation WWDC 2015 sample in ObjectiveC

Tags: objective-c, dependencies, sample, nsoperation, wwdc

I was going through Advance NSOperation WWDC 2015 session and at the end Apple provided us an Earthquake sample which is written in Swift.

I would be really grateful if I can get that sample in Objective C since I haven't yet started with Swift.

I wanted to rewrite my existing product Architecture as per WWDCApp architecture so that sample would be really addon.

If anyone can point me in correct direction it would be great.

Comment: Why rewrite something in objective-C? Apple supports swift-objective-C in same project.https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html

Answer (score 3):

On github, purrrminator has a repo. See this github repo: https://github.com/purrrminator/AdvancedNSOperations

Answer (score 1):

You will find here: [INSOperationsKit](https://github.com/inspace-io/INSOperationsKit) full port including unit tests, and deployment target <=iOS 7.0!